# Reference other project in solution without separate dll

Tags: c#, dll, reference, projects-and-solutions

At the moment I have added and referenced another project to my main solution. It works, but then I need the separate dll that is compiled.

How can I reference another project without the need for a separate dll that I have to distribute with my final exe?

Comment: Just add there reference as a project.  When you build your solution the reference solution will also build.

Comment: I guess it's not possible unless you make your delivery a static lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A C# class project in a Visual Studio solution always compiles to an assembly, so adding a project reference will inevitably mean that your executable references the assembly built as a result of compiling the other project. If you don't want to distribute the separate assembly with your executable the only thing you can do is to [ILMERGE](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17630) the assembly into your executable as a part of your deployment build process,

Comment: I will supply the dll with my program then.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  The way .net works is to load an additional assembly and using its meta data the classes inside that.  If you are attempting to have a set of classes that you refer to by source similar to the way c++ uses header files you will have to import those files into your project.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you're trying to statically compile a library. This is not (easily) offered by .NET without manually creating and merging assemblies.